# jQuery kendo grid how to add tooltip for icons edit, update, cancel, delete

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

working code link given below

[please click here to see the code](http://dojo.telerik.com/ojoViD)

I tried with title field, but mouse hover its not showing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>Kendo UI Grid Icon Buttons</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<style>
  
  .k-grid .k-grid-toolbar .k-grid-add,
  .k-grid tbody .k-grid-edit,
  .k-grid tbody .k-grid-update,
  .k-grid tbody .k-grid-cancel,
  .k-grid tbody .k-grid-delete {
    min-width: 0;
  }
  
  .k-grid .k-grid-toolbar .k-grid-add .k-icon,
  .k-grid tbody .k-grid-edit .k-icon,
  .k-grid tbody .k-grid-update .k-icon,
  .k-grid tbody .k-grid-cancel .k-icon,
  .k-grid tbody .k-grid-delete .k-icon {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example">
      <div id="grid"></div>

      <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var crudServiceBaseUrl = "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service",
          dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
              read:  {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              update: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              destroy: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              create: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                  return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                }
              }
            },
            batch: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            schema: {
              model: {
                id: "ProductID",
                fields: {
                  ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                  ProductName: { validation: { required: true } }
                }
              }
            }
          });

      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        pageable: true,
        height: 500,
        toolbar: [{name: "create", text: " "}],
        columns: [
          { field: "ProductName" },
          { command: [
            {name: "edit", text: { edit: " ", update: " ", cancel: " " }},
            { name: "destroy", text: " "}
          ], title: "Action", width: "250px" }
        ],
        editable: "inline"
      });
    });

  </script>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

added tooltip field and tried but I didn't get tooltip on mouse hover.
I need tooltip to show on mouse of each icons, in the action column
tooltip :- "Edit", "Update", "Cancel", "Delete"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a Kendo [ToolTip](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tooltip) for each button and point the [filter](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tooltip/configuration/filter) property to the button's class.

> Specifies a selector for the elements within the container which will display the Tooltip.

For example, to show a tooltip on each edit button you can do this:

```
$("#grid").kendoTooltip({
    filter: ".k-grid-edit",
    content: function (e) {
        return "edit";
    }
});
```

Here is a [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EhUFUFoL/11) with the full example below:

```
<div id="grid"></div>

<script>
    function hideKendoToolTips() {
      $(".k-tooltip").hide(); 
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var crudServiceBaseUrl = "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service",
          dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
              read:  {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              update: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              destroy: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              create: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                  return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                }
              }
            },
            batch: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            schema: {
              model: {
                id: "ProductID",
                fields: {
                  ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                  ProductName: { validation: { required: true } }
                }
              }
            }
          });

      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        pageable: true,
        height: 500,
        toolbar: [{name: "create", text: " "}],
        columns: [
          { field: "ProductName" },
          { command: [
            {name: "edit", text: { edit: " ", update: " ", cancel: " " }},
            { name: "destroy", text: " "}
          ], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
        ],
        editable: "inline",
        beforeEdit: hideKendoToolTips,
        cancel: hideKendoToolTips,
        save: hideKendoToolTips
      });
      
      $("#grid").kendoTooltip({
        filter: ".k-grid-edit",
        content: function(e){
          return "edit";
        }
      });
      $("#grid").kendoTooltip({
        filter: ".k-grid-delete",
        content: function(e){
          return "delete";
        }
      });
      $("#grid").kendoTooltip({
        filter: ".k-grid-update",
        content: function(e) {
          return "update";
        }
      });
      $("#grid").kendoTooltip({
        filter: ".k-grid-cancel",
        content: function(e){
          return "cancel";
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

You'll notice I added the function `hideKendoToolTips` and it's being called during the grid's `beforeEdit`, `cancel` and `save` events. Without this function, the tooltip will not hide automatically after clicking the edit, update or cancel buttons. I think it has to do with the button, the tooltip is assigned to, is removed when you click on it. Anyways this function is just there to hide the tooltip after you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dataBound event of the grid to add the titles to the buttons, for example:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    dataBound: function () {
         $(".k-grid-edit").attr("title", "Edit this record");
    },
...
```